# Large uipickerview on ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Does anyone know if the sdk provides a way to display a larger picker view on the iPad?
I see it in many iPad apps but not sure if it's a built-in ui element or not. If it's custom made where can. Find some sample code?

It looks kind of like this http://images.mobilism.org/?dm=VCIS
A check mark appears when you select it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `frame.size.width` to the value that fits your needs.

Comment: I want to change the height not width.

Comment: In your image there is no picker .that is the uipopovercontroller